# Applying a Regex to a Rich text Box in Umbraco 7

Tags: regex, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to apply a very simple regex to a Rich Text Box in Umbraco 7.

The regex I'm trying to apply is [^£\$].

I've tried some simple ones, [a-zA-Z], etc, but nothing seems to take effect.

Switching the property to as textString, and the regexes work immediately.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
john

Comment: Regular expressions work on the text, not objects. Perhaps, that is why.

Comment: That's the conclusion I've come to, but why would the RegEx box be available on it, if I can't use it on it?

Comment: I bet it is because the developers thought it was "not worth effort" to gray the field out.

Comment: If you really need to validate the RTE's value using a regex, you could create your own property editor and apply the validation logic there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the rich text editor in Umbraco has various settings and it can show different types of content.

Regular expressions are used to find matches inside *text* data only.

Thus, setting the content type to `textString` for regex-based search to work is logical.

The fact that the regex box is not grayed out when a non-supporting mode is selected is most probably a minor bug.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Umbraco 11. I was trying to match start `^` and end `$` of string, but it turned out what I needed was to match start `\A` and end `\Z` of an input. So to limit a Rich Text field to roughly 1000 characters I used `\A(\S|\s){1,1000}\Z`.

Regular Expressions Quick Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

A .NET Regex tester gave me a better idea of what to expect - http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: @Nick If you need to match the very end of string with .NET regex flavor, you should use `\z`, not `\Z`. Also, never use `(\S|\s){1,1000}`, no idea where you got this, but it is one of the slowest in the regex world. Just use `(?s:.{1,1000})`. In your case, `(?s)\A.{1,1000}\z`